# Google Map, display data at marker label in Laravel/JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps

The problem is when I pass the data controller to blade/JS, first I am converting it to JSON(because no other way) and then pass it to da javascript. But my label is not work properly. The script code is right below.

```
var estates = <?php echo json_encode($estates);?>

            function initMap()
            {
                var options =
                    {
                        zoom : 10,
                        center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
                    };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
                for (var i=0; i < estates.length; i++) {
                @foreach ($estates as $est)
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            label: estates.price,
                            position: {
                                lat: {{$est->lat}},
                                lng: {{$est->lng}}
                            }
                     });
                @endforeach
                }
            }
```

So if I try to pass price is like this `{{$est->price}}` then I get syntax token error. Because price is `varchar` with Japanese characters. So I need to convert it `Json` first and itetare it. But when I do that, there are no markers and label in the map. Just empty map, also there is no error in the console too? If I delete the JS `for` loop then markers are coming but no label...

Is anyone know what am I missing here?

Comment: Plz show from where you initialize `initMap` function. Check if you include google map script

Comment: I updated the code with script tag that include initMap callback. @JahidMahmud

Answer (score 1):

Try to use new google.maps.LatLng() function:

```
        var estates = <?php echo json_encode($estates);?>
        //estates = <?php echo json_decode($estates);?>
        function initMap()
        {
            var options =
                {
                    zoom : 10,
                    center : {lat:34.652500, lng:135.506302}
                }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

            for (var i=0;i<estates.length;i++){
            var latLng_ = new google.maps.LatLng(estates['lat'],estates['lng']);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: latLng_,
                    icon: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAy10Br9W1wWCSQNPc6f9CarvNEO4qqCg1BDbe7_mYZqHwXj3v',
                    label: estates['price']
                });


            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: estates['price']
            });

            marker.addListener('click', function () {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker)
            });
           }
        }
```

Comment: i am having a syntax error like before. iterating the data from DB but syntax? https://imgur.com/a/uSCCXan

Comment: I edited my answer. I put encodeURIComponent() to encode your db price info

Comment: thank you for update, but still same error at the same line. what do you think the reason is? Also is there any other option to change marker to DB fetched price? like I shared pic in the question...

Comment: what db are you using? If you use mysql you could use this command `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` before you query your table.

Comment: Yes, i am using mysql. I updated the question with the controller, how can I put this: `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` there? I am a bit confused, sorry for the burden.

Comment: Is your database config like this         'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

Comment: like this: mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'WOW'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'WOW'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'WOW'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

Comment: That is a better config

Comment: thank you but, any other suggestion :) is it impossible to fix this problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185777/discussion-between-mcbern-and-barbie).

Comment: yep, I tried still same error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: is it possible the pass the {{$estates->price}} array first a javascript var and after that encode it then iterate it in the label?

Comment: Try to json_encode the $estates then json_decode it before iterating

Comment: this is not working as well... is this thing really possible :)) it giving this time this error. unexpected indentifier at the estates at the top.

Comment: you are really taken care of me. thank for the update. error lost but no markers and no label... I update the question could you please check it?